# Global search does not work unless the user visits list view of the particular custom object first

Tags: salesforce1-app, custom-object, global-search

I have a fully prepared org with custom objects, layouts in it. For team work purpose I have created several users with system administrator profile and none of the users are able to global search records of an custom object unless they visit the default list view of that custom object first. We have 20+ custom objects and it is tiresome for them to go the list view over and over again every time a user is created. Any solutions?

Comment: When you say "does not work", do you mean it just doesn't show up in the "top" search results? You can click "show more" at the bottom left to show all. There's help documents that explain the behavior change in [Lightning vs. Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_desktop_mobile_comp.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) as well to understand what is expected specifically in [Lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=basics_search_records_lex.htm&type=5) where it only shows objects you "use" and you need to click "show more" to search all objects.

Comment: Actually it does not show on the top search result and even if I press enter and it redirects me to the result page, the records do not come. Once I visit list view of that object, then they show both in the top search result and redirected search page.

Comment: Screenshots may be helpful if possible. Is it on Lightning desktop, Classic desktop, mobile, custom search component, etc. I see you tagged "salesforce1-app" and you now mentioned "redirected" search page.